# Background and foreground Service For Execution

Tags: java, android, service, background, foreground

I am stuck in a problem in which I need to compute some concurrent calculation in the background and notify the user when each execution is completed.

I read a lot of articles. In which I found Service Class, Intent Service, and other ones. But I found crash above 24 android os versions.

> Nowadays which method is best to execute the background service in android and why?

Comment: We can talk about it in details. If you want @Durgesh Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above problem you can use Work Manager. For better understanding please review the following link

> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0):

Best Method to execute the Background service is to use the system `AlarmManager` class and invoke alarm after every XXX seconds but it will drain the bettery but solution definately work for you.
step to follow ,

1. create alarm

```java
    public static void setUpalarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestartServiceFromTimer.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context , 0,
                intent,0);
        // Setup periodic alarm every every half hour from this point onwards
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
        // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
        long delay = 5 * 1000 * 60; // time sets to 5 minute change accordingly
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
        }
```

2 create Broadcast receiver and restart service again also schedule alarm again

```java
    public class RestartServiceFromTimer extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Task Trigger","Task is triggered");
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(DetectIncomonCallService.class,context.getApplicationContext()))
        { Intent myserviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),Service.class);
            //start your background service here
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            {
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context.getApplicationContext(),myserviceIntent);//this is for forground service


            }
            else
            {
                context.startService(myserviceIntent);
            }
        }
        MainActivity.setUpalarm(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

3 call method from main activity like this

```java
setUpalarm(MainActivity.this)
```

Comment: I check this solution but in Oreo, foreground service will not execute more than five seconds.

Comment: no. Forground service will remain there . it will only stop when android receive more than three notification .Android remove the oldest notification.

Comment: make sure you have foreground permission in manifest for targeting android Oreo

Answer (score -1):

> You can use **Foreground Service** for android OREO and higher
>   versions and for below OREO Android version, you can use background **STICKY, NON_STICKEY services**. From the service, you can **broadcast** your action with value when your calculation is completed.